# Remove all white space from string JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, replace, trim

How can I remove all the white space from a given string.

Say:

```
var str = "  abc de fog   ";
str.trim();
```

Gives `abc de fog` **AND NOT** `abcdefog`, which I want.

How can I get all the white space removed using JavaScript?

Comment: str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');

Comment: Could you rename the Subject to something else than "Trim"? It's misleading when you ask for "replacing" in the text of your question.

Comment: You could also try: `str.replaceAll(' ','');`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use this:

```
str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Instead of this:

```
str.trim()
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining the preference? I'm assuming it is due to the fact that `str` can be `null` or `undefined`?

Comment: ```str.trim()``` only trims the trailing spaces at the beginning and end. The other solution strips out all the spaces from everywhere in the string.

Comment: Ah, so silly of me! I misread OP's original intent. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: This is not what OP wanted, he clearly said "abc de fog AND NOT abcdefog", `str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');` will do as @timothy-nwanwene suggested.

Comment: @0x48piraj you misread OP question. he wanted to strip ALL whitespace